# Quotient of factorials

Tags: factorial

> Prove that $${(n^2)!\over(n!)^{n+1}}$$ is an integer, where $n$ is a natural number greater than $5$.

I know how the product of $r$ consecutive numbers is divisible by $r!$ Could we use it here? If so how, if not please help with any other suitable method.

Comment: This is the number of ways in which you can divide a group of $n^2$ objects into $n$ groups of $n$ objects each when there is no ordering within the groups or between the groups.

Comment: Thanks I understood

Answer (score 3):

It's $$\frac{1}{n!}\binom{n^2}{n,n,...,n},$$ which is a natural number for all natural $n$ because there are $n!$ permutations exactly  of $(n,n,...,n).$

Comment: Ok to avoid the permutations of each group we are dividing by n! to obtain only the selections here divisions. Ok thanks I understand.

Comment: You are welcome!